# How to get dynamic Data from JSON into jvqmaps as a object not a array from php mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

Hi Brothers and Sisters

My First post , im new to json and am having a problem getting data into a jvqmap  I can get it working if I just add a var ie

```
var sample_data = ({
"gb":"6","us":"3"
 });
```

but not dynamically, I think in need to pass a a object as the inbound data is appearing as a json array in console just a hunch but don't have a clue how to do it with the ajax. json response below. if someone could assist I would be eternally grateful,1 years php not really cutting through the mustard.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'countries.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(json) {

         data = [];

         for (i in json) {
            data[i] = json[i];
         }  
//  var data = JSON.parse(json); 
    console.log(data);    
                },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" +        

   xhr.responseText);
        }
   });   
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({

      map: 'world_en',
    backgroundColor: null,
    color: '#ffffff',
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    selectedColor: '#666666',
    enableZoom: true,
    showTooltip: true,
    scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#006491'],
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
    selectedRegions: [],
    values: data_arr 
            ,

    onLabelShow: function (event, label, code) {

    if(data[code] > 0)
        label.append(': '+data[code]+' Attendees'); 
}  });
```

Countries.php page

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "wordpress2");
//$result = $conn->query("
$query = "SELECT * from countries";  
//MySQL query

$json = array();

$result = $conn->query($query);        //MySQL query is executed, and result stored in the variable $result

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){         //the result is an associate array, this array is assigned to $row variable

$json[] =  $row['CNT_ISO'].'"'. ':'. '"' .$row['attendees'] ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate an object like the one you manually created for testing, you can create a `stdClass()` object, fill its properties with the required data and then return that by calling `json_encode()` on your object and it will be converted automatically to a JSON String to be passed back to the javascript.

You can also make the query more efficient by only returning what you actually want from the query.

Its also a good idea to add some status checking after any query call.

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "wordpress2");

$query = "SELECT CNT_ISO, attendees from countries";  

$result = $conn->query($query);        
if ( $result === FALSE ) {
    echo $conn->error;
    exit;
}

$countries = new stdClass()   // create a new object

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){       
    $countries->{$row['CNT_ISO']} = $row['attendees'];
}
echo json_encode($countries);
```